# How to sum over values in a vector

Tags: matlab, vector, sum

say I have x = [1,2,5]
and f(x) = e^x
how do I sum f(x) over the values in x?

Comment: You mean this: `sum(exp(x))`?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use [`sum()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html):

```
x = [1,2,5];   
y = exp(x);
sum(y)
```

This will give you:

```
ans =

158.5205
```

Comment: `f(x) = exp(x);` seems like an odd choice of syntax for Matlab. Surely it will fail if `x` contains a non-integer?

Comment: just curious about it for general practice, I gotta minimize over fatsumzzzz

Answer (score 0):

If you're into micro-optimization; when the number of elements is small, using BLAS is slightly faster than a vectorized sum:

```
summation = ones(1,numel(x)) * exp(x(:));
```

or, if you are positive `x` is a row vector,

```
summation = exp(x) * ones(size(x)).';
```